# Facebook JavaScript SDK - OAuth Redirect URI Validation Issue when Exchanging Authorization Code

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently setting up Facebook Login. I'm using the `code` response type and successfully getting back an authorization code.
Attempting to exchange the auth code with an access token on the backend fails with this message:

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri
> is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request.

> Code: 100,
> SubCode: 36008

I'm using the `Facebook JS SDK` on the frontend, and while I correctly set the `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs`, I'm not specifying any redirect_uri when invoking the Facebook login dialog (with `FB.login(..)`), and no redirection is involved as the Facebook login dialog posts the auth code back to my app using `postMessage`. Even when I specify a `redirect_uri` when invoking the Login dialog, it gets ignored.

On the backend, when exchanging the code for an access token (with `oauth/access_token`), I tried all the allowed redirect URIs configured on the app, but nothing works and I get the same error.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: When I test this, the login dialog URL contains a redirect_uri value of `https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#...` with some URL fragment at the end. The fragment should be negligible, but the rest is what you'd need to pass in your exchange code for token call. Which makes this kinda problematic, because I'm guessing the `?version=46` is going to change at some point ...

Comment: I already tried using the redirect_uri from the login dialog, but any URL not included in my app's domains gets rejected:
`Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains`

Comment: I thought it might be white-listed per se (the have a similar URL for desktop apps), but if that is not the case ... then I don't know how exactly this is currently supposed to work either. Or if it _is_ supposed to work, because the `response_type` parameter isn't even documented (any more?) for login with the JS SDK, as far as I can tell. I would either get the token directly on the client side, if you want to continue using the JS SDK for login; or implement the server-side login flow instead.

Comment: I'm actually using Facebook Login for Business, and I think at some point, the implicit flow (where you can get the token directly on the client) will not work for that product, and you'll have to use the authorization code flow. The only solution I can think of right now is to manually trigger the Login dialog: [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow/)

Comment: I'm running into this. I did find a line on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/ that says

> If in-app browser scenarios are important for your web app, you should add the domain of your login page to the Allowed Domains and also its full URI (including the path and query parameters) to the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. If you have a lot of variation in the URIs where Login happens for your app, you can manually specify a fallback_redirect_uri as an option in the FB.login() call so you only need to add that one entry to your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs list.

Comment: but I am not sure if the fallback_redirect_uri comes into play when fb is validating whether the redirect_uri values match -- this may just be advice on getting past the allowlist validation for redirect_uri

Comment: Did either of you ever figure this issue out?  I'm running into the same problem

Comment: I ditched the SDK for login. I'm redirecting to the login endpoint manually. Take a look at this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow/

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!  My only concern is that with this flow even though the page says "{App} connected to Facebook" the actual oauth redirect doesn't occur until the user clicks "Got it",  did you run into this as well?  Any workarounds?

Comment: That's how it should be. Nothing can be done about that I think.